# Python Normalising a list of numbers failing/Pandas normalise row by row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of mass spectra for different samples. I am trying to normalise the intensities of the signals for each sample so that I can compare between samples.

To that end, I am looping through each file, collating the data into a single pandas dataframe, with each sample on a row, and the columns as the variables. Thus, the cells hold the values associated with the sample and variable.

Whilst I am filling the dataframe, I try to normalise the list (sample) against the total of itself - so that each row in the final dataframe will add up to 1.

For example:

```
for y in files:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(inputloc+y,index_col=0)
    totalRA = df2["Rel. Abundance"]
    totalRAlist = totalRA.tolist()
    totalRAsum = sum(totalRAlist)
    for i in range(len(df2)):
        form = df2.loc[i]["Formula"]
        RA = df2.loc[i]["Rel. Abundance"]
        RAnorm = float(abs(RA)/totalRAsum)
        outputdata.loc[y[:-9]][form] = RAnorm
```

As far as I can tell, it is correctly filling the dataframe, however when I sum each row:

```
outputdata.T.sum()
```

I get values less than 1.0 for the majority of my samples. Sum are as low as 0.747389, which suggests its more than just a truncation/float issue?

I try to debug it by adding a summing variable and printing it through the loop.
I.e.

```
a = 0
for i in range(len(df2)):
    form = df2.loc[i]["Formula"]
    RA = df2.loc[i]["Rel. Abundance"]
    RAnorm = float(abs(RA)/totalRAsum)
    a = a + RAnorm
    print a
```

This does *always* add up to 1 for each sample.

As such, I don't know where I'm going wrong.

---

Alternatively, is there an easy way to normalise each *row* of a Pandas Dataframe so that each row sums to 1?

---

EDIT:
Example input data:

http://dumptext.com/8ky1RX8F

[image: Example Output]

Example output file (not-normalised)

So each row (each sample) is normalised to the total sum of it's values.

Comment: can you post a sample for input data (5-10 rows from one of your CSV files) and expected output data set?

Comment: you may also try to normalize columns of transposed dataframe...

Comment: Edits made for MaxU.

Comment: why abs(RA) in  RAnorm and not  in the TotalRAsum ? if some values are <0, this can explain....

Comment: @Popher, in the provided input data assuming that first unnamed column is the "Sample#" - i have always only one "Rel. Abundance","Formula" for each "Sample#"  - how do you pivot them? I.e. In the output table there would be set only one column always (different ones)... Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @MaxU I have a larger script which is reading in the "formula" columns from each CSV (each sample is a CSV). I produce one total list of formula, and then a "set" of that list - i.e. a list of all the formula in all the samples. This becomes the column headers for my output dataframe. 
Each row then represents a sample, and the values are read from each input CSV for each formula.

Comment: @BM -  I threw the abs() in there to test. With or without it isnt working. (No values should be less than 0, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an assumption that the first unnamed column in your CSV file is `"Sample#"`, so I've also named it as `Sample` in the input CSV file.

Beside that i've slightly modified the input data, so that we would have a few `"Rel. Abundance","Formula"` per `Sample#`.

Here is what i came up with:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', usecols=['Sample', 'Rel. Abundance', 'Formula'])

# pivot input data
pvt = df.pivot(index='Sample', columns='Formula', values='Rel. Abundance').fillna(0).reset_index().set_index('Sample')
print(pvt)

# normalize data
norm = pvt.div(pvt.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

# check sum of rows
norm['sum'] = norm.sum(axis=1)

# output
print(norm)
```

Output:

```
Formula  C10H16O2  C10H16O3  C10H18O2  C10H18O3    C10H20O2  C11H20O2  \
Sample                                                                  
0               0         0         0         0           0         0   
1         5300142         0         0         0           0         0   
2               0         0  22442914         0           0         0   
3               0         0         0         0  8355451392         0   
4               0   4886962         0         0           0  16859592   
5               0         0         0  16221800           0         0   

Formula  C8H14O4  C9H10O4  C9H14O4   C9H18O2   C9H18O3  
Sample                                                  
0              0  5157540        0  70453296         0  
1        5217051        0        0         0         0  
2              0        0        0         0         0  
3              0        0        0         0  11975477  
4              0        0        0         0         0  
5              0        0  6799955         0         0  
Formula  C10H16O2  C10H16O3  C10H18O2  C10H18O3  C10H20O2  C11H20O2  C8H14O4  \
Sample                                                                         
0         0.00000  0.000000         0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000   
1         0.50395  0.000000         0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.49605   
2         0.00000  0.000000         1  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000   
3         0.00000  0.000000         0  0.000000  0.998569  0.000000  0.00000   
4         0.00000  0.224724         0  0.000000  0.000000  0.775276  0.00000   
5         0.00000  0.000000         0  0.704629  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000   

Formula   C9H10O4   C9H14O4   C9H18O2   C9H18O3  sum  
Sample                                                
0        0.068212  0.000000  0.931788  0.000000    1  
1        0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    1  
2        0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    1  
3        0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.001431    1  
4        0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    1  
5        0.000000  0.295371  0.000000  0.000000    1
```

Output explanation:

1st DF - `pvt` pivoted input data

2nd DF - `norm` normalized DF (made of the pivoted data)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear - each input CSV is a single sample. The first column in the CSV is the index for a  "peak" for that sample. Each sample may have thousands of peaks. 
I'm trying to collate all the peaks for all the samples into a matrix I can then do data analysis on.

All I'm stuck on at the moment is why my normalization doesnt work - summing all the "Rel Abundance" for a given CSV, then dividing each value against that total. The resultant sum should be 1 - but it isnt.

Comment: I've taken your suggested way to normalise the data though, and that works!         
outputnorm = outputdata.div(outputdata.sum(axis=1),axis=0)